# Number of Ways of Writing $r$ as a Sum of Distinct Positive Integers, all atleast $s$: $c_{r,s} =\sum_{i=1}^{r-s} c_{i,r+1-i} +1$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, recurrence-relations

For $r,s \ge 1$, let $c_{r,s}$ be the number of ways of writing $r$ as a sum of distinct positive integers, all greater than or equal to $s$. Then I believe the following recurrence holds:

$$c_{r,s} =\sum_{i=1}^{r-s} c_{i,r+1-i} +1$$

$c_{r,1}$ also happens to be the coefficient of $x^r$ in $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1+x^i)$.

First of all, is this correct? Assuming it is, can $c_{r,s}$ be expressed in closed-form? If this recurrence has already been studied before, I welcome any references as well.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Odd_parts_and_distinct_parts

Comment: @saulspatz That article talks about $c_{r,1}$. How about $c_{r,s}$?